# Why do the two Euclidean Dirac 'measure's change via the same rule under local chiral transformations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-anomalies

I am reading Weinberg QFT vol 2 p.362~370, which is on calculating the Abelain anomaly.

On p.369, the book says the two Dirac spinors $\psi$ and $\overline{\psi}$ are entirely independent in the Euclidean field theory.

**My first question** : why are they entire independent in the Euclidean metric?

Also, Weinberg goes on to define the local chiral transformations as
\begin{equation}
\delta \psi:= i \alpha(x)t \gamma_5 \psi(x)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\delta \overline{\psi}:= -i \alpha(x) \overline{\psi(x)} t \gamma_5 
\end{equation}
where $\alpha(x)$ is an infinitesimal parameter and $t$ is a not necessarily traceless Hermitian matrix.

Then, he claims that the functional measure $[d\psi][d\overline{\psi}]$ transforms as
\begin{equation}
[d\psi][d\overline{\psi}] \to [\text{Det } \mathfrak{U}]^{-2} [d\psi][d\overline{\psi}]
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\mathfrak{U}_{mx, ny}:=[e^{i\alpha(x)t \gamma_5}]_{m,n}\delta(x-y).
\end{equation}

Here, $m$ and $n$ are spinorial and (possibly) flavor indices.

**My second question** : Even if $\delta \overline{\psi}= -i \alpha(x) \overline{\psi(x)} t \gamma_5 $, how can we get the above transformation rule for the measure? What happens to $[d\overline{\psi}]$?

Could anyone please explain?

Comment: Don't you just have to recognise the approximation of the expinential function?

Comment: The approximation seems to be based on the expression $[\text{Det } \mathfrak{U}]^{-2}$. So, I wonder how this expression comes out..

Comment: Two families of variables, two transformation matrices $\mathfrak {U}$.

Comment: But the two transformation matrices seem to cancel each other...